# Grepping for value at a specific location in a line

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a file where each line consists of a sequence of 16 numbers separated by a space.  I want to find every line that has a value of 500 for the 8th number in the sequence.  What grep regex can I use to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Awk is good for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using repetition in grep:

```
grep '^\([^ ]\+ \)\{7\}500 ' file
```

It means 7 columns with something, followed by 500 and a space.

Comment: This is the answer I eventually came up with.  Using grep -E lets you omit the backslashes fyi to anyone who may see this later!

Answer (score 3):

You are not at this point just grepping, but splitting lines in fields, which means that you should use awk:

```
cat 3.txt | awk '{if ($8 == "500") print $0}'
```